# php apache root write permission

Tags: php, apache, permissions

Can i write /etc/apache2/ directory. 
I want to create a file with php and apache. But i must root.
Is there a way to sudoers?

Can do this?

Comment: are you saying you want a PHP web page program to have write access to its own Apache server's private folders? Ouch.

Comment: You don't need write access to the apache2 folder to create a php web application. Instead try finding the `htdocs` folder and put your php file there.

Comment: @Spudley, i can write apache directory. @erikb i know.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the group of /etc/apache2 to the same group that apache runs as and give the group write permission. This might be safer than trying to su with php and a system call.

Answer (score 0):

Any directory that you want the Apache process to write to needs to be writable by the user that the Apache daemon runs as. So you either need to make the directory world-writable (ie chmod 777) or owned by the Apache user.